# React-native: FlatList get refs to scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm currently building an app with react native:

this is my flatlist:

```
    <FlatList
      ref={"myFlatList"}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
```

In this function I want to scroll to a specific index:

```
  _enableTVEventHandler() {
    this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {
        this.refs["myFlatList"].scrollToIndex({viewPosition: 0.5, index: 2});
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

But I have an error:
Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things that I can see,

1. You need not define string refs within `{}`. However React docs suggest you to make use of ref callback

Do it something like

```
 <FlatList
      ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
    />
```

2. You need to bind your function to be able to refer to the correct context

Do it like

```
_enableTVEventHandler = () => {
    this._tvEventHandler = new TVEventHandler();
    this._tvEventHandler.enable(this, function(cmp, evt) {
        this.myFlatList.scrollToIndex({viewPosition: 0.5, index: 2});
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

or

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props) ;
    this._enableTVEventHandler = this._enableTVEventHandler.bind(this); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried but I have the same error

Comment: You inner function has a binding, but how about the outer one i.e `_enableTVEventHandler `

Comment: My function is called here :   componentDidMount() {
    this._enableTVEventHandler();
  }

Comment: I need to bind it ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to bind that

Comment: I have a problem when I tried to bind it : this._enableTVEventHandler().bind(this);

Comment: You don't bind it like that at the time of calling , either do that in the `constructor()` and call as you are calling. I will update the code with the aproach tooo

Comment: I can't do that In componentDidMount ? Because I need to do that In this place

Comment: Glad to help :), You should always look at whether your function have proper binding or not if you face any such issues

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)