# Why do we reference flatlist in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I wanted to auto scroll my React native flatlist. I have seen couple of posts on stack overflow, developers referred flatlist in flatlist components. My question is when and why we refer flatlist in React Native.

Comment: It would be easier if you showed some of these posts and asked why they do it in that case. In general you would refer to an element if you need to access it directly, but we can't know why they would need to access the flatlist directly in the posts you saw.

Comment: You can see a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936486/react-native-flatlist-get-refs-to-scroll

Answer (score 0):

To need `ref` to access methods in a component.
If you want to focus a TextInput you would get the ref like this,

`ref={ref => this.myInput = ref}`

Then you can focus the TextInput by calling `this.myInput.focus()` anywhere in that component